# trying to create an android template for cocos2d-x but getting cygbin error

Tags: android, cmd, cocos2d-x

i have eclipse setup to run the android sdk just fine.

i followed a few tutorials

i changed
NDK_ROOT_LOCAL="C:\eclipse\android-ndk-r9"
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_LOCAL="C:\eclipse\android-sdk-windows"

in the create-android-project.sh

then when i run the create-android-project.bat i get a popup error that says
there is no disk in the drive, please insert a disc into the drive \device\harddisk2\DR2

and CMD reads couldn't find cygwin at "e:\cygwin\bin"

any ideas of what this means, the tutorials said nothing about cygwin, so im not sure what it means

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the create-android-project.bat, open with `Notepad++` Edit the paths given there to where you have installed cygwin and android-ndk.